# Combining Sql and NoSql databses in to an API service

Tags: database, database-design

I have been asked to build a SpringBoot POC based on a relationship data set.

For context purposes you can consider an HR system data set.

If chose to build a monolithic app, I can use just SQL database.
If I use microservices patterns, I would need to use Sql and NoSql databases.

Is there a real world scenario where I would split the data between the 2 databases?
Like separation of concerns?

Is there a scenario where one would choose to use 2 databases?
To me it doesn't make any sense, but I might not be experienced enough to have had a scenario like this.

Comment: It's hard to say in general, but most document databases I've seen have a relational database to hold the document metadata and a document database to hold the images/documents.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. What do you mean by document database to hold images/documents. Does that mean I could use SQL to store metadata and NoSQL to store images? And cross reference when searching for an image if I want to get the the metadata as well? So, I could have 3 options: Get metadata, get image, get metadata&Image?

Comment: Yes, you could use SQL to store metadata and NoSQL to store images.  SQL implies a relational database and NoSQL could mean any number of databases.

Comment: so, in essence I could Use SQL to store my data base blue print. and No SQL in case I would need to return/store a certain record composed of particular metadata, all I would need to do is get the record, from that database, instead of filtering through my SQL? would this design not result in data being out of sink? I suppose if a record gets updated, the particular data that get's updated could be updated in all places where that particular element is changed. Or it can only be updated where I would like to be updated and keep a database without being updated.